# NOT LIKE in where condition is too slow

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using "LIKE" operator in a query it returns the result quickly but when I use same query with "NOT LIKE" it takes too long to return results.

For example:

```
SELECT COL1, COl2, COL3 FROM TABLE WHERE COL4 LIKE 'G%'
```

Above query return results faster and the following query is too slow

```
SELECT COL1, COl2, COL3 FROM TABLE WHERE COL4 NOT LIKE 'G%'
```

Any alternative ways to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is col4 indexed? If not, create an index.

This may speed up your query:

```
SELECT COL1, COl2, COL3 FROM TABLE WHERE COL4 < 'G' or COL4 >= 'H'
```